# Start Windows Service Automatically On Starup?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-services

I am installing my windows service and starting the service via a batch file. However sometimes I notice that my windows service stops for some reason. I think the reason might be because a windows update happens and a reboot of the server happens.

When I look at the service I see startup type as "Manual" so I believe that it does not restart.

How can I change my code to start as automatic startup?

```
cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
InstallUtil.exe C:\Websites\Scheduler\Scheduler.exe
NET START "MyService"
```

Comment: Change your installer so that it sets the Startup Type when it creates the service or use the `SC` command to change the startup type.

Comment: Ah did not know there was an option on the installer was looking into SC but if can set it on the installer then will do that.

Answer (score 1):

#### Method for Windows 8 and 10

- Create a shortcut of your batch file.
- Right click the shortcut and select cut.
- Open start and type run and press enter.
- Type "shell:startup".
- Once the Startup folder is opened, click the Home tab at the top of the folder and select Paste to paste the shortcut file into the Startup folder.

#### Method for Windows 7, Vista and XP

- Create a shortcut to the batch file.
- Once the shortcut is created, right-click the shortcut file and select Cut.
- Click Start, then Programs or All Programs. Find the Startup folder and right-click that folder, then select Open.
- Once the Startup folder is opened, click Edit in the menu bar, then Paste to paste the shortcut file into the Startup folder. If you do not see the menu bar, press the Alt key to make the menu bar visible.

By using these methods, you can make your batch file automatically run at the startup.

But if you want only the service starts at the startup use:

```
sc config myservice start= auto
```